# Multiple choice test GUI with serialization of Q&A

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, persistence

I'm working on a project for school in Java programming. I need to design a GUI that will take in questions and answers and store them in a file. It should be able to contain an unlimited number of questions.  We have covered binary I/O.

How do I write the input they give to a file?  How would I go about having them add multiple questions from this GUI?

```
package multiplechoice;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MultipleChoice extends JFrame {
     public MultipleChoice() {
   /*
    * Setting Layout
    */
    setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10));

    /*
     * First Question
     */

     add(new JLabel("What is the category of the question?: "));
     JTextField category = new JTextField();
     add(category);

     add(new JLabel("Please enter the question you wish to ask: "));
     JTextField question = new JTextField();
     add(question);

     add(new JLabel("Please enter the correct answer: "));
     JTextField correctAnswer = new JTextField();
     add(correctAnswer);

     add(new JLabel("Please enter a reccomended answer to display: "));
     JTextField reccomendedAnswer = new JTextField(); 
     add(reccomendedAnswer);

     add(new JLabel("Please enter a choice for multiple choice option "
             + "A"));
     JTextField A = new JTextField();
     add(A);

     add(new JLabel("Please enter a choice for multiple choice option "
             + "B"));
     JTextField B = new JTextField();
     add(B);

     add(new JLabel("Please enter a choice for multiple choice option "
             + "C"));
     JTextField C = new JTextField();
     add(C);

     add(new JLabel("Please enter a choice for multiple choice option "
             + "D"));
     JTextField D = new JTextField();
     add(D);

     add(new JButton("Compile Questions"));
     add(new JButton("Next Question"));


 }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*
     * Creating JFrame to contain questions
     */
    FinalProject frame = new FinalProject();
   // FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("Questions.dat");


    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

 //   button.setLayout();
 //   frame.add(panel);

    panel.setSize(100,100);

   // button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100)); 
    frame.setTitle("FinalProject");
    frame.setSize(600, 400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: What I/O have they covered in the course?  I find it odd that the school requires you to serialize the Q&As when you seem to have no ideas about how to go about it.  Note there are 3 or 4 places, and at least a dozen ways, to persist (store and retrieve) information between runs.

Comment: they have covered binary I/O

Comment: @AndrewThompson unless the school expect them to serialize the object (literally, using the java serialization mechanism) to a file. Therefore binary I/O is more then sufficient. This would of course require to create a `Q&A` type of object which gets constructed from the UI, and which can then dumped to file

Answer (score 2):

#### First:

There are basically two ways to write to a file in java.

1. `ObjectOutputStream(FileOutputStream("blah"))` [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)
2. `PrintWriter("blah")` [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)

#### Second:

> Three or more; use a for.

This is what comes to mind for me when reading `JTextField A = new JTextField();` and `JTextField B = new JTextField();`

Comment: *"they have covered binary I/O"* (copied from comment to question) Huh.  That seems odd to me in that 'binary I/O' is usually seen as quite different from 'text I/O' (in which we need to account for the encoding, like UTF-8 or CP-1252).  That in turn would seem to favor Nick's point 1), rather than a `PrintWriter` which I would  tend to use for basic (human readable) output.  I inherently do not like object serialization due to the huge caveat that it might not be readable across different Java versions.  Though that probably would not be considered a problem in this case.

Comment: Did you mean to post this in reply to Bobby? "I inherently do not like object serialization due to the huge caveat that it might not be readable across different Java versions." I've had pretty good luck in that corner. On the other hand, if you want to get at the data using a different language, you are pretty much SOL.

Comment: I intended my reply to both of you, given I was mostly referring to points in your existing answer.  Good point on the 'other language', I might consider XML serialization for this type of structure (especially accounting for multiple choice questions) but it seems it is beyond the immediate scope of the course (maybe?).

Comment: @AndrewThompson, Lemme put it like this: If I was doing this assignment, I'd use ObjectOutputStream. If I was actually trying to make a useful application, I'd use Python's Flask backed by SQLite.